# Jaxb unmarshal xml sequence to map

Tags: java, dictionary, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have two classes `Foos` and `Foo` that are supposed to be serializable/deserializable to/from XML:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foos")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Foos", propOrder = { "foo" })
public class Foos {

    protected Map<Foo, Foo> foo;

    public Map<Foo, Foo> getFooMap() {
        if (foo == null) {
            foo = new HashMap<Foo, Foo>();
        }
        return this.foo;
    }

    @XmlElements(value = { @XmlElement })
    public Collection<Foo> getFoo() {
        return getFooMap().values();
    }

}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Foo", propOrder = { "name" })
public class Foo {

    protected String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

For algorithmical reasons I cannot use a `List<Foo>` but need a `Map<Foo, Foo>`. Each `Foo` should be put into the `Map` both as key and value.

Marshalling a `Foos` object to XML works because I have the `getFoo` getter, but unmarshalling from XML does not. This is probably because the unmarshaller does not know how to convert the xml sequence of `Foo` objects into a hash map.

**How can I tell this to the unmarshaller?**

I think I need a method like this (pseudocode):

```
public void fillMap(XMLSequence<Foo> sequence) {
    for (Foo foo : sequence)
        getFooMap().put(foo, foo);
}
```

And then it probably needs some xml annotations as well.

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using two fields:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foos")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Foos", propOrder = { "fooList", "foo" })
public class Foos {

    @XmlElement(name="foo")
    protected List<Foo> fooList;

    protected Map<Foo, Foo> foo;

    public Map<Foo, Foo> getFooMap() {
        if (foo == null) {
            foo = new HashMap<Foo, Foo>();
            if (fooList != null)
                for (Foo f : fooList)
                    foo.put(f,  f);
        }
        return this.foo;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Collection<Foo> getFoo() {
        return getFooMap().values();
    }

}
```

- During unmarshalling, the `fooList` is filled with the data from the `<foo>...</foo>` xml elements.
- When `getFooMap` is called for the first time, it is filled with the content of `fooList` (by putting the same object as key and value).
- During marshalling, the method `getFoo` is called which will return the values of the `foo` map.